# C++ std::unique is not showing what I am expecting from it

Tags: c++, c++11

I was trying to find if the vector contains duplicates (please don't provide an algorithm to check duplicates.) I came up with this weird behavior. std::unique on vector 1,2,3,1 should make it 1,2,3,1 returning an iterator to 1 but on erasing the iterator returned till the vector.end() I got the same size vector as that of I original vector. Here is the snippet of code depicting the said behavior (available at [ideone](https://ideone.com/D2g5hK))

```
    vector<int> nums2 = {1,2,3,4};  
    vector<int> nums = {1,2,3,1};
    cout << "nums1" << endl;
    vector<int> a(nums.begin(), nums.end());
    auto ip = unique(nums.begin(), nums.begin()+nums.size());
    nums.resize( std::distance(nums.begin(),ip) );
    cout << a.size() <<  " " << nums.size() << endl;

    cout << "Nums2" << endl;
    vector<int> a2(nums2.begin(), nums2.end());
    auto ip2 = unique(nums2.begin(), nums2.begin()+nums2.size());
    nums.resize( std::distance(nums2.begin(),ip2) );
    cout << a2.size() <<  " " << nums2.size();
```

The actual output is

```
nums1
4 4
Nums2
4 4
```

but it  should have been

```
nums1
4 3
Nums2
4 4
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::unique` only removes consecutive duplicates. From cppreference.com on [`std::unique`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) :

> Eliminates all but the first element from **every consecutive group of equivalent elements** from the range [first, last) and returns a past-the-end iterator for the new logical end of the range.

Your 1s are not consecutive so they aren't removed. This is the expected behavior. A quick solution is to first [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) your range.

Comment: As a general solution/advice, this is not great, as it changes the order of elements. Also not great from complexity standpoint.

Comment: @SergeyA, probably, this is a reason why there is no counterpart of `std::unique` in the Standard library to remove non-consequtive unique elements.

Comment: Well that's what I was missing. Thanks, the duplicates should be **consecutive**. Thanks for clearance, I just missed it.

Answer (score 2):

You are misunderstanding what std::unique does; it eliminates all but the first of any *consecutive* runs of elements. That is, it will not remove duplicates that are t adjacent. 
Thus, to remove duplicates, you need to make sure all duplicates are located next to each other; the simplest way to do this with a std::vector is to first apply std::sort, and then std::unique.

Comment: This will change order of elements, and thus not a general solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like to remove duplicate elements, while keeping their first occurrences in order, `unique` is not what you want. Instead, use an `unordered_set` to keep track of the elements you've seen so far. (You can do this with `remove_if`, but I wouldn't advise it unless you're familiar with lambda capture semantics; just do it in a for-loop, and read up on how to properly erase elements from a vector in a for-loop.)